# Apache configuration: only 2 sub-domains with SSL

Tags: apache

I have been trying for hours to get something that seems simple to work. I have a domain name with two subdomains. I would like to redirect my subdomains from HTTP to HTTPS and deny any other request with a 404 page, including the main domain.

```
http:||sub1.example.com -> https:||sub1.example.com
http:||sub2.example.com -> https:||sub2.example.com
http:||example.com -> 404
https:||example.com -> 404
http:||www.example.com -> 404
http:||something.example.com -> 404
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  ServerName example.com
  Redirect 404 /
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub1.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https:||sub1.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub2.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https:||sub2.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  ServerName sub1.example.com
  DocumentRoot /etc/sub1
  <Directory /etc/sub1>
    # ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On
  ServerName sub2.example.com
  DocumentRoot /etc/sub2
  <Directory /etc/sub2>
    # ...
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Problems:

http:||example.com redirects to https:||example.com
I expected a 404 without redirecting

http:||sub2.example.com redirects to https:||example.com
This don't work at all

sub1 works